# Взаимоизменение numpy списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, списки, numpy

Подскажите, как называется этот эффект, чтобы про него почитать и, главное, как от него избавиться:
Создаю 2 списка

```
box_1 = [[1,1],[1,4]]
box_2 = box_1
```

После этого меняю значения во втором списке, но при этом меняется и в первом.

```
box_2[1][1] = 577
print(box_1)

[[1, 1], [1, 577]]
```

Comment: Почитайте про ссылочные типы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [NDArray.copy()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html), чтобы создать копию Numpy массива вместо ссылки (*reference*) на объект:

```
In [177]: box_1 = np.array([[1,1],[1,4]])

In [178]: box_2 = box_1.copy()

In [179]: box_2[1, 1] = 577

In [180]: box_1
Out[180]:
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 4]])

In [181]: box_2
Out[181]:
array([[  1,   1],
       [  1, 577]])
```